# Escape special characters using haystack SearchQuerySet and Solr

Tags: python, django, solr, search-engine, django-haystack

When I try to search something with special character does not find. I have added the neccesary filters in solr_schema.xml.

When I do a search with Solr (console) using characters scape, it works.

Example:

```
 title_element:\+
```

result:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">title_element:\+</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="clean_content">textocontilde</str>
<str name="django_ct">core.element</str>
<str name="django_id">28</str>
<str name="id">core.element.28</str>
<str name="text">textocontilde</str>
<str name="title_element">dsfsdfsfd hola+</str>  
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

When I try to use SearchQuerySet, does not work-

```
sqs_title_element= SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(title_element='\+')
```

what is wrong, the engine has the configuration.

filetype configuration:

```
 <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Thanks for you answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you add in the analyzer this filter

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true"    expand="true"/>
```

And do this in python code.

```
from haystack.inputs import Clean
clean_value = Clean('+')
```

look that didn't escape the character.

Need to use filter not autoescape.

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(title_element=clean_value)
```

I had the same problem and it worked for me.